# How to fetch the value of the second input tag in the html snippet below?

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

```
<td>
   <input class="checkboxColumn" name="An" value="9FFF8546C9E9A200F7780550E6A4B6F9610B29D3A" type="checkbox">
   <input id="AList" name="AList" value="9FFF8546C9E9A200F710550E6694B6F9610B29D3A|Disabled" type="hidden">
</td>
```

I have above td as first column in the Jquery datatable. I Need to fetch the value of the #AList using below javascript logic. But the alert below shows the value 
of first input tag for all rows when iterates. What are the changes I need to make to display value of second tag?

```
    var rows = oTable.fnGetNodes();
    for (var i = 0; i < oTable.fnSettings().aiDisplay.length; i++) {
        debugger;
        // Get HTML of 3rd column (for example)
        alert($($(rows[i]).find("td:eq(0)").html()).val());
        }
```

On displaying

`alert($(rows[i]).find("td:eq(0)").html());`

The alert shows complete markup of contents of `<td>`

I need output as `"9FFF8546C9E9A200F710550E6694B6F9610B29D3A|Disabled"`

Comment: The `.html()` function gets the innerHTML from the tag. Try removing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `html()` gets the content as html. You need to access the `input` in the `td` and then get it's value with `val()`.

```
alert($(rows[i]).find("td:eq(0) #AList").val());
```

For Example you can see here(In example I intentionally get the `table` then the `td`)

```js
console.log($('table').find("td:eq(0) #AList").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>
   <input class="checkboxColumn" name="An" value="9FFF8546C9E9A200F7780550E6A4B6F9610B29D3A" type="checkbox">
   <input id="AList" name="AList" value="9FFF8546C9E9A200F710550E6694B6F9610B29D3A|Disabled" type="hidden">
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Descriptive answer. Works

Answer (score 0):

alert($(rows[i]).find("td #AList").val());

This should work. You will be able to get the value desired.

Answer (score 0):

If you generalize the case for all second input box in the td then use the pseudo selector - nth-child(n).

```
alert($(rows[i]).find("td>input:nth-child(2)").val());
```